What is the slice timing or slice order information of the Neurocon & Taowu datasets?
The websites lack crucial information on slice timing and slice order, which are essential for preprocessing fMRI data.
Neurocon:

Parkinson's Disease Datasets - Neurocon (https://portal.conp.ca/dataset?id=projects/Neurocon)

Primary Publication: "Exploring the reproducibility of functional connectivity alterations in Parkinson's disease" by Liviu Badea et al. (PLoS ONE, https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0188196)

GitHub repository: https://github.com/conpdatasets/Neurocon

Source: http://fcon_1000.projects.nitrc.org/indi/retro/parkinsons.html


Taowu:

Parkinson's Disease Datasets - Taowu (https://portal.conp.ca/dataset?id=projects/Taowu)

Primary Publication: "Exploring the reproducibility of functional connectivity alterations in Parkinson's disease" by Tao Wu (PLoS ONE, https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0188196)

GitHub repository: https://github.com/conpdatasets/Taowu

Source: http://fcon_1000.projects.nitrc.org/indi/retro/parkinsons.html



If the information isn't available publicly, it's unlikely anyone here can help you, I would contact the authors directly.

@BryanKrause I have emailed both authors several times but haven't received any response.
None of the above websites have open discussion features, and I can't find relevant information online.
After reviewing the papers, I still can't find the related information.
However, these two pieces of information (slice timing and slice order) are crucial for data preprocessing - otherwise, we can only make assumptions.

Then you're probably out of luck. Be sure you're trying to contact the senior authors, any student authors are most likely out of academia by now.

@BryanKrause OK. Thank you for your suggestions.
